# Ошибка при объявлении глобальной переменной Cannot redeclare

Tags: php, linux

Есть функция, в ней определяется глобальная переменная `$_PEAR_destructor_object_list`, но при вызове скрипта появляется ошибка :

> "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _pear_call_destructors() (previously declared in /usr/local/www/apache22/data/smart/lib/PEAR/PEAR.php:776) in /usr/local/share/pear/PEAR.php on line 777".

Причем сам сайт работает под Denwer нормально, но при переносе на сервер появилась такая ошибка.

```
function _PEAR_call_destructors()
{
    global $_PEAR_destructor_object_list;
    if (is_array($_PEAR_destructor_object_list) &&
        sizeof($_PEAR_destructor_object_list))
    {
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Уточню, проблема с самой функцией _pear_call_destructors(), которая вызывается с помощью register_shutdown_function().

Answer (score 1):

Перевожу на русский: функция `_PEAR_call_destructors` дважды определена. [Вот](http://kartikeya-patel.blogspot.com/2009/06/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare.html) решение проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо! Но решение проблемы было добавление в .htaccess строчки php_value include_path ".:/path/to/php/PEAR"